# No correlation but coefficient of both valid?

Tags: regression, correlation

I have two variables, **output** and **number of hours worked**. I want to predict how many hours we need to spend for a certain output. First i tried a regression analysis but unfortunately there is no correlation between these two variables. Is there another way to predict the production output based on the hours spent?
Can i use the factor between these two variables as a estimator or would that be wrong because there is no correlation?

[image]

Comment: When there is no correlation between the variables, they could still be dependent in some non-linear transform. But looking at your data ... I don't think you have enough samples to have much statistical power.

Answer (score 1):

Thank-you for including the data in a table. Several points I should bring up. First is that you found an outlier that you didn't use $(5807,1162.25)$. Second, when this outlier is excluded the correlation goes from significant to insignificant $(p=0.0154,0.6183)$. Wondering what is responsible for this I performed a Spearman rank correlation on the whole data, which gave me $p=0.9206$. So the two variables do not appear to covary. I then tried transformation of data, Deming regression, OLS in $y$, OLS in $x$, median regression etc. with the result that although sometimes I could make significant regressions, mostly I could not. For example OLS in $y$ had a negative slope, but when I switched axes for plotting data, so did OLS in $x$, which is not consistent with a significant slope, indeed, after testing neither slope was significant.

So, if you want to predict $y$ you can use mean $y$, $\bar{y}$, and if you want to predict $x$ you can use $\bar{x}$ (or median $x$ given the outlier) to do so. However, the data just is not correlated. So what that means is although a minimum error estimate of $y$ is $\bar{y}$, it has nothing to do with the value of $x$, and vice-versa for $x$ and $\bar{x}$. Thus, there is no significant linear covariance leaving the data centroid $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ or their respective medians as predictors of location of the data.

Having said that much, that does not mean that some relationship does not exist between $x$ and $y$, just that no linear relationship is apparent. That underlines the need to actually know a lot about what $x$ and $y$ are physically. For example, look at the figure below.

[image]

The upper left panel shows a blob of $(x,y)$ data with no apparent relationship. Now if we are told that this data is actually $x=r\sin \theta$, and $y=r\cos \theta$, as in the upper right figure, then it is not implausible that the data originated from an $x=\theta$ and $r$ is radius, laid out as a Cartesian plot in the lower figure. Indeed, that was how the top left figure was created, from the data as show in the lower plot. Now the point is, that the upper plots have insignificant correlation, and the lower very strong correlation. Thus, no significant linear relationship (correlation is normalized covariance) only means that covariance explains ($r^2$ is A.K.A. explained fraction) an insignificant amount of the $(x,y)$ variance. However, it does not exclude some other functional or physical relationship between $x$ and $y$. As one simple example, if we know that $(x,y)$ are repeat normally distributed estimates of a single non-zero datum, and if we know *a priori* that the relationship is linear and passes through $(0,0)$, then $y=\frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}x$ becomes a valid (maximum likelihood) estimator, with zero correlation at the estimated point. This may seem like a lot of if's, but consider that is how one could calculate the acceleration of gravity using the velocity at one meter of an object falling from rest. Thus, the physical properties of the measurement system must be considered prior to interpreting any of its statistics.

Comment: The data represents not the hours worked of one person. Several persons over a longer period of time. The period is same for each data point. http://www.filedropper.com/data_50

Comment: Other question is if it would be legit to use a factor for assumption how many hours i will need. For example i divide time by output and use the average factor as an predictor. Would that be correct? As an "alternative" for the linear regression?

Comment: No, it would not in this case. See answer after I fix it up.

Comment: Thank you very much. So it means i need to find a better variable for predicting my output. So for my understanding: I can never use a factor between to variables for prediciting one of them when these to variables are not correlated correct?

Comment: In this case there is no useful relationship between variables, as exemplified by a lack of useful correlation among other things. If you want to predict y, something better correlated than x would be useful. Not having a significant correlation is not always an indication of no useful relationship between variables, for example, if the data is arranged in a spiral, there might be no correlation in Cartesian coordinates, but a good one in polar coordinates.